# JSON Schema dependency based on minimum value

Tags: json, dependencies, jsonschema

I am trying to add a dependency to a property based on the property value before it. Within my JSON, there is an instances property. If that property is > 2 only then show the StartIndex property. I have tried adding another if-then-else to my pre-existing one (wrapped in an allOf) but that was failing so I decided to take the dependency route.

Here's the JSON Schema with my attempt at adding the dependency withing the StartIndex property:

```
{
  "definitions": {},
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "http://example.com/root.json",
  "type": "object",
  "title": " ",
  "required": [
    "NetworkProfile",
    "GroupEmailAddress",
    "FILESTORAGE",
    "Memory",
    "Instances",
    "StartIndex"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "Name": {
      "$id": "#/properties/Name",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Name",
      "default": "",
      "description": "The first five characters are generated per <a href=\"https://confluence.dell.com/display/AD/Common+Questions#CommonQuestions-HowisthenameoftheVirtualMachinedetermined?\" target=\"_blank\">specs</a>. Specify the next eight characters here and we suggest: Data Center (2), Layer (2-3), Sequential Number (2).",
      "examples": [
        ""
      ],
      "minLength": 0,
      "maxLength": 8,
      "pattern": "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$",
      "validationMessages": {
        "pattern": "Must contain only alphanumeric characters.",
        "required": "Must contain only alphanumeric characters."
      }
    },
    "Instances": {
      "$id": "#/properties/Instances",
      "default": 2,
      "examples": [
        "2"
      ],
      "pattern": "^(.*)$",
      "title": "Number of VM Node",
      "description": "Number of VM instance in this request",
      "minimum": 1,
      "maximum": 5,
      "type": "number"
    },
    "StartIndex": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Instances": {
          "minimum": 2
        }
      },
      "$id": "#/properties/StartIndex",
      "default": 1,
      "examples": [
        "1"
      ],
      "pattern": "^(.*)$",
      "title": "Start Index for these VMs",
      "description": "The starting sequence number for this set of servers",
      "type": "number",
      "minimum": 1
    },
    "Memory": {
      "$id": "#/properties/Memory",
      "type": "number",
      "enum": [
        4,
        8,
        16
      ],
      "title": "RAM (GB)",
      "default": 4,
      "examples": [
        ""
      ],
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    },
    "GroupEmailAddress": {
      "$id": "#/properties/GroupEmailAddress",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Group Email Address",
      "default": "",
      "description": "This should be an email address for your application group. Security will use this email address to contact when TLS cert needs to be renewed.",
      "examples": [
        ""
      ]
    },
    "User": {
      "$id": "#/properties/User",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Admin Group",
      "default": "",
      "examples": [
        ""
      ],
      "description": "The user account that will have access to the vm. Default belong to requester if not specified. Additional users can be added by using a comma(,) as a separator. <br> (e.g. Americas\\firstName_lastName). Only PAC group is accepted for PROD.",
      "pattern": "^((Americas|Asia-Pacific|Europe)\\\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_.%]*[*,]?[\\s]*)*$"
    },
    "NetworkProfile": {
      "$id": "#/properties/NetworkProfile",
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "APP",
        "WEB"
      ],
      "title": "Server Type/Function",
      "description": "Web Server is meant to serve static pages e.g. HTML and CSS, while Application Server is responsible for generating dynamic content by executing server side code.",
      "default": "",
      "examples": [
        ""
      ],
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    },
    "eDell": {
      "$id": "#/properties/eDell",
      "title": "Is the VM related to <a href=\"https://confluence.dell.com/display/AD/Common+Questions#CommonQuestions-WhatiseDell?\" target=\"_blank\">eDell</a>? ",
      "type": "boolean",
      "default": false
    },
    "Disks": {
      "$id": "#/properties/Disks",
      "type": "array",
      "title": "Local (Non-OS) Storage. Default OS Drive (C) size is 60GB. The (D) drive is fixed at 20 GB, can use E-Z for additional storage. Can only add an additional 900GB.",
      "items": {
        "$id": "#/properties/Disks/items",
        "type": "object",
        "title": " ",
        "required": [
          "data"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "data": {
            "$id": "#/properties/Disks/items/properties/data",
            "type": "object",
            "title": " ",
            "required": [
              "capacity",
              "initial_location"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "capacity": {
                "$id": "#/properties/Disks/items/properties/data/properties/capacity",
                "type": "number",
                "title": "Capacity (GB)",
                "default": "",
                "examples": [
                  "20"
                ],
                "minimum": 5,
                "maximum": 900
              },
              "initial_location": {
                "$id": "#/properties/Disks/items/properties/data/properties/initial_location",
                "type": "string",
                "title": "Drive Letter",
                "default": "E",
                "examples": [
                  "/u02"
                ],
                "description": "Drive Letter of the partition without colon",
                "pattern": "^[eE,fF,gG,hH,iI,jJ,kK,lL,mM,nN,oO,pP,qQ,rR,sS,tT,uU,vV,wW,xX,yY,zZ]{1}$",
                "validationMessages": {
                  "pattern": "C,D are reserved use E-Z.",
                  "required": "C,D are reserved use E-Z."
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "FILESTORAGE": {
      "$id": "#/FileStorage",
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "YES",
        "NO"
      ],
      "title": "Add File Storage",
      "default": "NO",
      "examples": [
        ""
      ],
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    }
  },
  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "FILESTORAGE": {
        "const": "YES"
      }
    }
  },
  "then": {
    "properties": {
      "NASDisk": {
        "$id": "#/properties/NASDisk",
        "type": "object",
        "title": "File Storage",
        "required": [
          "AppName",
          "SizeGB",
          "Protocol",
          "ShareOwner",
          "Function"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "Protocol": {
            "$id": "#/properties/NASDisk/properties/Protocol",
            "type": "string",
            "default": "CIFS",
            "options": {
              "hidden": "true"
            }
          },
          "Function": {
            "$id": "#/properties/NASDisks/properties/Function",
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "File",
              "Storage",
              "Backup",
              "App",
              "Log",
              "Database",
              "Repository"
            ],
            "title": "Choose Function for NAS",
            "default": "File",
            "examples": [
              ""
            ],
            "pattern": "^(.*)$"
          },
          "AppName": {
            "$id": "#/properties/NASDisk/properties/AppName",
            "type": "string",
            "title": "App Name",
            "default": "",
            "description": "Abbreviation or alias of the application name to be prefix to the share name, limit to 10 letters",
            "pattern": "^[a-zA-Z]{1,10}$"
          },
          "SizeGB": {
            "$id": "#/properties/NASDisk/properties/SizeGB",
            "type": "number",
            "title": "Size (GB)",
            "default": 5,
            "examples": [
              5
            ],
            "minimum": 5,
            "maximum": 500
          },
          "ShareOwner": {
            "$id": "#/properties/NASDisk/properties/ShareOwner",
            "type": "string",
            "title": "Share Owner",
            "default": "",
            "description": "User account with ownership of the share. Group ownership can be specified using the format DOMAIN\\UserName.  <br> (e.g. Americas\\firstName_lastName).",
            "examples": [
              "adms_c_lawlor"
            ],
            "pattern": "^((Americas|Asia-Pacific|Europe)\\\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_.%]*[*,]?[\\s]*)*$"
          },
          "FC_Members": {
            "$id": "#/properties/NASDisk/properties/FC_Members",
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Comma separated AD groups that will have full control of share."
          },
          "RW_Members": {
            "$id": "#/properties/NASDisk/properties/RW_Members",
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Comma separated AD groups that will have read/write control of share."
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "else": {}
}
```

Here was my allOf attempt:

```
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "FILESTORAGE": {
            "const": "YES"
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "NASDisk": {
            "$id": "#/properties/NASDisk",
            "type": "object",
            "title": "File Storage",
            "required": [
              "AppName",
              "SizeGB",
              "Protocol",
              "ShareOwner",
              "Function"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "Protocol": {
                "$id": "#/properties/NASDisk/properties/Protocol",
                "type": "string",
                "default": "CIFS",
                "options": {
                  "hidden": "true"
                }
              },
              "Function": {
                "$id": "#/properties/NASDisks/properties/Function",
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [
                  "File",
                  "Storage",
                  "Backup",
                  "App",
                  "Log",
                  "Database",
                  "Repository"
                ],
                "title": "Choose Function for NAS",
                "default": "File",
                "examples": [
                  ""
                ],
                "pattern": "^(.*)$"
              },
              "AppName": {
                "$id": "#/properties/NASDisk/properties/AppName",
                "type": "string",
                "title": "App Name",
                "default": "",
                "description": "Abbreviation or alias of the application name to be prefix to the share name, limit to 10 letters",
                "pattern": "^[a-zA-Z]{1,10}$"
              },
              "SizeGB": {
                "$id": "#/properties/NASDisk/properties/SizeGB",
                "type": "number",
                "title": "Size (GB)",
                "default": 5,
                "examples": [
                  5
                ],
                "minimum": 5,
                "maximum": 500
              },
              "ShareOwner": {
                "$id": "#/properties/NASDisk/properties/ShareOwner",
                "type": "string",
                "title": "Share Owner",
                "default": "",
                "description": "User account with ownership of the share. Group ownership can be specified using the format DOMAIN\\UserName.  <br> (e.g. Americas\\firstName_lastName).",
                "examples": [
                  "adms_c_lawlor"
                ],
                "pattern": "^((Americas|Asia-Pacific|Europe)\\\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_.%]*[*,]?[\\s]*)*$"
              },
              "FC_Members": {
                "$id": "#/properties/NASDisk/properties/FC_Members",
                "type": "string",
                "description": "Comma separated AD groups that will have full control of share."
              },
              "RW_Members": {
                "$id": "#/properties/NASDisk/properties/RW_Members",
                "type": "string",
                "description": "Comma separated AD groups that will have read/write control of share."
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "else": {
        
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "Instances": {
            "minimum": "1"
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "StartIndex": {
            "$id": "#/properties/StartIndex",
            "hidden": true,
            "default": "1",
            "examples": [
              "1"
            ],
            "pattern": "^(.*)$",
            "title": "Start Index for these VMs",
            "description": "The starting sequence number for this set of servers",
            "type": "number",
            "minimum": 0
          }
        }
      },
      "else": {
        "properties": {
          "StartIndex": {
            "$id": "#/properties/StartIndex",
            "default": "",
            "examples": [
              "1"
            ],
            "pattern": "^(.*)$",
            "title": "Start Index for these VMs",
            "description": "The starting sequence number for this set of servers",
            "type": "number",
            "minimum": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

UPDATE: So I actually figure this out using nested properties as shown here

````
"isMultiDropdown": {
      "title": "",
      "$id": "#/properties/isMultiDropdown",
      "required": [
        "isMulti"
      ],
      "type": "object",
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "isMulti": {
            "const": "YES"
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "StartIndex": {
            "$id": "#/properties/StartIndex",
            "default": "",
            "examples": [
              "1"
            ],
            "pattern": "^(.*)$",
            "title": "Start Index for these VMs",
            "description": "The starting sequence number for this set of servers",
            "type": "number",
            "minimum": 0
          }
        }
      },
      "properties": {
        "isMulti": {
          "$id": "#/properties/isMultiDropdown/isMulti",
          "enum": [
            "YES",
            "NO"
          ],
          "title": "Are you provisioning multiple instances?",
          "default": "NO",
          "examples": [
            ""
          ],
          "pattern": "^(.*)$",
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
    ```
````

Comment: What do you mean "... only then show the StartIndex property."? Could you provide example data you expect to pass and fail validation please?

Comment: I want to only display that property if the instances property is > 2, or thinking about it another way: hide that property (maybe using an if-then or a dependency) if the instances property is = 1.

Here is an example: A user provisions 3 instances of a Virtual Machine, I want the form to give them the option to type in starting index. If a user provisions only 1 instance, then it is redundant to show them the start index field as there will only be one Virtual Machine. Does that make sense?

Comment: What do you mean "display" and "hide"?

Comment: oooooh you're making a form from JSON Schema. For that you'll need to specify what library you're using. Making forms from JSON Schema is non standard, and so will be library dependant. Most form generating libraries do not support modern versions of JSON Schema.

Comment: We're using version 7 I believe: http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#

Comment: That would be the version of JSON Schema. You'll need to share what library you are using to make forms from JSON Schema. Making forms from JSON Schema is NON STANDARD and not defined by the JSON Schema specification, so any such generation is application defined.

Comment: It is rendered by an application downstream, but I believe this is the repo: https://github.com/hamzahamidi/ajsf so it's using angular.

Comment: Unless it's documented as something it supports, it's probably not supported. Form generation from JSON Schema is usually very limited. Best of luck.

Comment: It seems like it shouldn't be that hard. I need to conditionally show a property, based on the enum value of the one before it.

Comment: Either the library supports it, or not. If you don't care about if it's JSON Schema or not, consider using https://surveyjs.io, which allows you to create more complex forms defined using JSON, with validation. It just doesn't use JSON Schema.

Comment: So the library definitely supports use of allOf and if-then, knowing that - would it be possible to show a property conditionally? In my schema I do this elsewhere, but the properties being added are appended to the bottom of the form, I want this new property to show up in the middle of the form, right after the dropdown before it.

Comment: Where is the documentation for this? I cannot find it.